# how to determine buckets while creating a hive table

Tags: hadoop, hive

I like to insert a 1.5 GB file into a hive table first I created with 1000 buckets then with 40 buckets and with 5 buckets but it is taking so many times please help with this.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Renganthan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It Depends on your use case for example if you want to load the data into table where reads are very less and writes are more it is recommended to keep little higher number of reducers to make write fast. Because map reduce job will invoke the same number of reducers as number of buckets which means faster write.

For general case.
As per the rule of thumbs your buckets size should be approximately equals to your block size for example if your data size is 1.5 GB and block size is 128 MB then so

1500MB/128MB ~= 12

so you can keep your number of buckets as 12.

other way to decide is to make you buckets size such they can be fit into memory. This will help you in achieving Buckets joins based on that you can calculate buckets in same way as mentioned above

Comment: thanks for your answer I kept 15 atlast attempt but I took more than 10 min to execute the following query "insert into table renga partition(yeared) select * from crime3".  Can you please explain why it is happening.

Comment: Check if your data is skewed ? On which column you are bucketing if your job is taking too much time at 99% thn your data may be skewed which causing slow write